# RxJS: How to subscribe to inner observable only when outer observable/subject is subscribed to?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, reactive-programming, rxjs5

**Background**

Using Typescript and RxJS, I'm trying to extend a behavior subject so that it takes an observable as a construction parameter and then subscribes to it so that each value from the observable gets set as the value of the behavior subject.

**Question**

How do I make it so that the behavior subject is only subscribed to the inner observable when the behavior subject itself has at least one subscriber?

**Code**

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';

export class SubjectWithInnerObservable<T> extends BehaviorSubject<T> {

    constructor(
        initialState: any,
        someObservable: Observable<T>
    ) {
        super(initialState);

        // I only want this subscription to exist when there are one or more subscribers to the behavior subject
        someObservable.subscribe(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you want this? Also Subjects themselves are observables and produce values so what's wrong with just having the behavior subject emit the value?

Comment: I removed a bunch of context to remove the noise and focus on the part I need help on. The observable that gets injected is actually coming from a service that connects to websockets when there is at least one subscriber. I don't want that connection live if it doesn't have to be. In addition, there is actually going to be come complex mapping/translation of the value that comes off the observable before it gets assigned to the behavior subject, but I didn't want to show that.

Comment: It's a behavior subject because the value that gets stored in it is actually an accumulation of what comes through the observable and I want new subscribers to get the accumulated value.

Comment: Ok, so you already have the value update, and if you are talking higher order observables then you want to `mergeMap` or `switchMap` it depending on your use case.

Comment: You mean instead of a behavior subject? I think it would still need to be a behavior subject as I need the accumulated state to stick around when there aren't any subscribers.

Comment: I am saying use those operators to flatten your observable produced by your behavior subject.

Comment: I can't say I understand what you're suggesting. Any chance you could provide some sample code?

Comment: I would encapsulate `BehaviorSubject` not extend it.

Comment: `is only subscribed ... when ... has at least one subscriber` sounds like `refCount`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `.publishBehavior()` operator on the websocket, which internally has a BehaviorSubject.

The 'publish' bit means it won't emit until connected, like a tap on a hose.

Add to that the `.refCount()` operator and you get auto-connect on subscription, i.e a tap that's controlled by subscription count.

Docs: [RefCount](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/refcount.html)

**Demo**

```js
// mock websocket
const ws = new Rx.Subject()

const autoConnected = ws
  .do(x => console.log('ws emits', x)) // just to show ws stream
  .publishBehavior(null)  // make connectable, i.e only emit when subscribed
  .refCount()             // auto-connect on subscribe
  .filter(x => x)         // filter out that pesky initial value

ws.next(1) // before subscription - never emits

const subscription = autoConnected.subscribe(x => console.log('1st subscription', x))
ws.next(2)
ws.next(3)

subscription.unsubscribe()
ws.next(4)  // after unsubscribe - never emits

autoConnected.subscribe(x => console.log('2nd subscription', x))
ws.next(5) // after re-subscription - emits last plus next
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.6/Rx.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is just simply perfect. I'm not going to admit how many lines of code I wrote trying to accomplish what you did in 5. Kudos man. I appreciate your time.